# Syntax Error - Update query MS access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am getting syntax error for below code: Please help

```
 db.Execute "UPDATE Account_Manager_Details" _
    & "SET count = count + 1 " _
    & "WHERE ID = " & id & ";"
```

Thanks You.

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Comment: Also, `count` is a reserved word in SQL, use `[count]` or better: rename the column.

Answer (score 1):

You need a space between the table name and the "SET" statement.

`db.Execute "UPDATE Account_Manager_Details "`

It's a good idea to assign your SQL statement to a string before you execute it, then you can see exactly what you are doing.

```
sSQL = "update account_manager_details ... " _
db.execute sSQL, dbfailonerror
```